# Angular DI - Can't Inject any dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am developing a demo app in angular 5 I've had an annoying problem with DI,
I can't seem to inject anything to any service/component unless I use the @Inject tag.

I tried to isolate the problem by deleting unrelated files and it still persists

I know it's not conventional but this issue could have so many explanations that I don't think sharing code snippets is going to help. I'm going to share a very small (50kb) rar with my project so you can play with it and maybe point me in the right direction.

This is my project after extensive isolation of the problem :
[MyApp](https://files.fm/u/nfv46p4t)

Run:

> npm install
>
> npm start

Comment: What makes you think that the service is not injected? In the code above, is it `HttpClient` that does not get injected? Or is it `ItemsService` that you cannot inject? If so, can we see the code where you inject it? One common problem with services occurs when a service has more than one provider in the application.

Comment: The HttpClient is not injected, I get `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ItemsService: (?).`

Comment: I noticed most Angular app examples don't inject a service into the root component. I'm wondering if there are issues with this. I've had a similar error trying to import services into AppComponent, whereas with child components I haven't.

Comment: But I'm trying to inject a service into a service, not the app component